# When i use findparameterdistribution parameters are diffient from in reasearch why?

Tags: parameters

This is Chen weibull distribution

```
pdf= ProbabilityDistribution[(1 - Exp[λ*(1 - Exp[1])])^(-1) *λ*β*(γ/α)*(x/α)^(γ - 1)*
  (1 - Exp[-(x/α)^γ])^(β - 1)*Exp[λ*(1 - Exp[-(x/α)^γ])^β - (x/α)^γ + (1 - Exp[-(x/α)^γ])], 
  {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {λ > 0, β > 0, α > 0, γ > 0}]

data = {70, 90, 96, 97, 99, 103, 104, 104, 105, 107, 108, 108, 108, 
109, 109, 112, 112, 113, 114, 114, 114, 116, 119, 120, 120, 120, 
121, 121, 123, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 128, 128, 129, 129, 130, 
130, 130, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 132, 132, 132, 133, 134, 134, 
134, 134, 136, 136, 137, 138, 138, 138, 139, 139, 141, 141, 142, 
142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 144, 144, 145, 146, 148, 148, 
149, 151, 151, 152, 155, 156, 155, 156, 157, 157, 157, 157, 158, 
159, 162, 163, 163, 164, 166, 166, 168, 170, 174, 201, 212};
```

And `aic` for it in research is 859.704 for parameters

[image]

and this affect on the coparsion between distribution Which code can give me this aic and ks=0.092 you can see the data and chen-weibull distribution on https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/25742558.2020.1721401#_i6

Comment: You copied the code from an [answer to your earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240818/43522), but as JimB already remarked: the PDF is not normalized. You cannot expect sensible results from an unnormalized PDF. I highly suspect you made a mistake while copying the formula from your source.

Comment: I put URL because anyone can sure from data and PDF for distribution I want to reach to this results anyone can help me

Comment: the results of Chen weibull I can't get by Mathematica if anyone can code this to obtain aic=859.704and ks =0.092 the data above

Comment: You should write the authors about what software they used.  Some software packages leave off constants which results in different AIC values although differences in AIC values among different models aren't affected.

Comment: What about ks could you write code for it

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the paper, I think the correct definition for your distribution is:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
  {"CDF",
   Divide[
    1 - Exp[λ (1 - Exp[(1 - Exp[-(x/α)^γ])^β])],
    1 - Exp[λ - λ Exp[1]]
    ]
   },
  {x, 0, ∞},
  Assumptions -> {λ > 0, β > 0, α > 0, γ > 0}
]
```

Give it another try with this definition.